# Where is the words in ' ' located?

Tags: php, mysql, html, server, windows-10

I am learning php, (absolute beginner) and want to know where the words in '' are located. I downloaded a code from online for a login system and am trying to learn how it works. Here is the code portion:

```
<?php

// any HTML input *must* be HTML-escaped to prevent the user from injecting malicious JavaScript code
function html_escape($raw_input, $encoding)
{
return htmlspecialchars($raw_input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, $encoding);
}

/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1) {
$first_name = 'Guest, Please Login or Sign Up to Play!';
$last_name = '';
}
else {
// Makes it easier to read
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
}
?>
```

So where it says, "`if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1) {`", when it says `logged_in`, where would that be defined? Is it defined in another file with the `$logged_in`, or what?

Also, i found some file where it says "`$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`" but i don't know if it means something, if it does please tell me!

Thanks so much.

(i'm a beginner so go easy on me please)

Comment: Being a beginner does not prevent you from googling `php $_SESSION`

Comment: I tried, but i cant seem to understand it :)

Comment: if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1) checks if the user is logged in or not in fact this is not a login form , this whole code is just to check if the user is log in or not and is normally included on top of every page of your website

Comment: somewhere in some file is the code `$_SESSION['logged_in']=1;`

Comment: if you are a beginner then you should start by learning variables and if statements don't start with a login form because that needs mysql

Comment: i understand mysql, but not variables.. yes, i am weird lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the code you shown, this is the check login step in login process. In login process, there is two step we need to do:

1. **Check login**: determine that current session is logged in or not. If not, shown/redirect to login page.
2. **Login page**: is used to input username & password and check inputed value. If username & password is correct, we save a value to `$_SESSION` to flag this user is logged in.

To find how the `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is set, you must find in your downloaded code the check login section.

In general this can be simple as:

```
if ($_POST['username'] == 'abc' && $_POST['password'] == 'xyz') {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
    // some code to refresh or redirect to main content
}
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Why did someone down-vote this answer? It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in `$_SESSION` variables after `session_start();` and assign values to it with:

`$_SESSION['keyname'] = 'value';`

You can write apostrophe (`'`) or double quote (`"`) to save string variables.
More informations here: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php

Your code `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1)` is just a boolean check if `$_SESSION['logged_in']` is set to 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`). 
So it checks your `$_SESSION` array with the key `logged_in` if 1 is set or not.

I hope I could help you with that?

Answer (score -1):

Assume you have form with field 'username' and 'password' at HTML:

```
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='username'>
  <input type='password' name='password'>
  <input type='submit' value='Login'>
</form>
```

after clicking 'Login' button you will run login.php:

```
<?php
  $allowedUser = 'johnny';
  $allowedPass = 'mypassword';

  session_start();
  if (($_POST['username']!= '') && ($_POST['password'] !=''))
  {
     if (($_POST['username'] == $allowedUser) && ($_POST['username'] ==  $allowedPass))
     $_SESSION['is_loged'] = 1; // session variable will be set when you have allowed credentials
  }
?>
```